# Crashed while deleting by confirmationDialog which's based on swiftUI and realm

Tags: swiftui, crash, realm

To explain the crash I made a MRE(Minimal, Reproducible Example) below:

The entrance:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ForTestApp: App {
    @StateObject private var store = SpaceStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(store)
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: SpaceStore
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Add") {
            for id in 0...5 { SpaceStore.add(by: "tag: "+id.formatted()) }
        }
        Divider()
        if let spaces = store.spaces {
            ForEach(spaces) { space in
                RowView(space: space)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(SpaceStore())
}
```

RowView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RowView: View {
    let space: Space
    @State private var ifShowDialog = false
    @State private var ifShowSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(space.name)
            Button("sheet") {
                ifShowSheet.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $ifShowSheet) {
                Button("Delete") {
                    SpaceStore.delete(space)
                }
                Button("ConfirmationDialogDelete") {
                    ifShowDialog.toggle()
                }
                .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $ifShowDialog) {
                    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                        SpaceStore.delete(space)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
import RealmSwift

class Space: Object, Identifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
class SpaceStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var spaces: Results<Space>?
    
    static let realm = try! Realm()
    private var realmToken: NotificationToken?
    
    init() {
        let results = SpaceStore.realm.objects(Space.self)
        realmToken = results.observe { _ in
            self.spaces = results
        }
    }
    
    static func add(by name: String) {
        let space = Space(name: name)
        try! SpaceStore.realm.write {
            SpaceStore.realm.add(space)
        }
    }
    
    static func delete(_ space: Space) {
        try! SpaceStore.realm.write {
            SpaceStore.realm.delete(space)
        }
    }
}
```

The deleting action works well in the sheet while crashed in the confirmationDialog.

And the item was deleted succeeded when I checked the database.

I'm a newer to swiftUI, if someone could point out the reason that cause the crash and tell me how to deal with it, it would be great helpful.

Comment: Don’t use ! Without checking there is actually a value

Comment: embed in `if let`, crashed all the same.@loremipsum

Comment: you haven’t shared the error but it is likely a disconnect with what you are showing and the time it takes for Mongo update the array. That is why using the wrappers is better. I’m sure mongo has documentation on how to keep you array current. Somehow you have to remove the object you are deleting from the view before mongo deletes it.

Comment: As you can see I connected the realm and swift by this way `self.spaces = results`. How to remove an object of swift before realm delete it indeed ? I‘ve seen somebody assign the results to an array like this `self.spaces = Array(results)` . But I don't think it's a proper way to use realm cause it's results is 'lazy' as the documentation says which will cause a huge waste on querying. Do you have any suggestions which's more specific? I'll implement and verify it. @loremipsum

Comment: I don’t, I don’t have a MongoDB setup right now to test your code. Your reassignment is asynchronous so for a frame or two the object isn’t there, that is likely why your app is crashing, the Array is a better solution because you can remove from the array before you remove from realm, they the view will remove any reference to the object before it is gone

Comment: Seems to find the difference between `sheet` and `confirmationDialog`. The crash as you say 'the object isn’t there as the reassignment is asynchronous' didn't appear when the object was deleted in a `sheet`, the reason maybe @escaping  `@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content` which avoid the dependency to superview that has been destroyed. And the object in `confirmationDialog ` didn't 'escape', it's just a ViewBuilder  like this `@ViewBuilder actions: () -> A`. @lorem Epsom